# Windows Shutdown command option to not show the signing out window

Tags: windows, command-line

How can we hide/not show this blue signing out screen when executing the `shutdown.exe /l`.

Use Case: I have an Azure App Launcher, that launcher has options to launch remote apps, and to close the session. So user opens a remote app and later clicks on close session to sign out of remote session. User see this annoying blue signing out screen.

I have tried the following for the `close session`:

`shutdown.exe /l` - current implementation, shows the blue screen

`shutdown.exe /l /f` - same behavior, shows the blue screen

'logoff.exe /n' - doesn't close any remote apps before logoff

'logoff.exe /f' - doesn't close any remote apps before logoff

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to end the session, use the command:

```
tsdiscon.exe
```

You can also remotely execute the command

```
tsdiscon.exe /server:fqdn.foo.bar 42
```

Comment: And if you want the disconnected session to then be logged out, configure group policy to automatically end disconnected sessions after a short timeout period.